# Import Project from Spyder2 to Spyder3

Tags: python, python-3.5, projects-and-solutions, spyder

The past few months, I've been working on a project using Spyder2 IDE with Python 2.7. However, now I'm being instructed to look into ways of translating the program from Python 2.7 to Python 3.5, which means I'm using Anaconda3 now instead of Anaconda2, and that means I'm using Spyder3 as the default IDE instead of Spyder2. I want to be able to import the entire project, but Spyder3 does not recognize it as such. So how to I import a Spyder2 Project into the Spyder3 IDE?

Comment: You may want to have a look at the issue I just opened (I use python 2.7, but the problem is the same: projects from Spyder2 are not recognized by Spyder3): https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3598

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy solution to this, at least for simple cases and as of May 2017 (Spyder 3.1.2): Create a new empty project in Spyder 3.  The new project directory will then have a subdirectory named ".spyproject" with these files in it: codestyle.ini, encoding.ini, vcs.ini, workspace.ini.  Copy the entire .spyproject subdirectory to the old Spyder 2 project directory.

This allows Spyder 3 to at least see the source files in the old project directory, even if all the settings don't track.

I only have dumb use cases (e.g. no "related projects") in my Spyder 2 projects.  But this way I don't have to generate 75 new projects and manually import the old files.

Comment: Sorry for not creating a way of importing Spyder 2 projects in Spyder 3. Spyder 2 projects were defined a long time ago and never finished completely. That's why I decided to rewrite them from scratch.